How on news page component to get resulting data of other component calling?
In laravel 10 / "livewire/livewire 3.4 app in app/Livewire/Cacheable/HotNews.php component I made class for calculating and
grouping data and keeping them in cache of the app:
<?php

namespace App\Livewire\Cacheable;

use App\Enums\ConfigValueEnum;
use App\Enums\NewsPublishedEnum;
use App\Library\Services\Interfaces\KeyDataInterface;
use App\Library\Traits\{AppCommonTrait, DataCachingTrait};
use App\Models\KeyData;
use App\Models\News;
use App\Models\Reaction;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Livewire\Component;

class HotNews extends Component
{
    public $reactions = [];
    use AppCommonTrait, DataCachingTrait;

    protected string $keyDataIdentifier;
    protected int $companyId;
    public int $cachingTimeInSeconds = 60 * 10;
    public bool $writeDataCaching = false;
    public bool $useDataCaching = false;
    public string $cachedData = '';

    public function mount(int $companyId)
    {
        $this->companyId = $companyId;
        $this->keyDataIdentifier = 'hot-news-cache-by-company-' . $this->companyId;
        $this->cachingTimeInSeconds = 60 * (int)ConfigValueEnum::get(ConfigValueEnum::CACHED_HOT_NEWS_BLOCK_MINUTES);
        $this->useDataCaching = ConfigValueEnum::get(ConfigValueEnum::USE_DATA_CACHING, false); // Reference to USE_DATA_CACHING parameter in .env file
        $this->cachedData = $this->readDataCaching($this->keyDataIdentifier);
        if (!$this->useDataCaching or empty($this->cachedData)) { // if cache clear - need read data from db and save in cache
            $this->retrieveDbData();
            $this->writeDataCaching = $this->useDataCaching;
        }
    }

    public function render(): string
    {
        if($this->cachedData) { // There is cached data
            return $this->convertCachingData($this->cachedData);
        }

        // If has no cached data - needs to generate it from blade view
        $renderedCode = view('livewire.Cacheable.hot-news', ['reactions' => $this->reactions])->render();
        if($this->writeDataCaching) { // Use cached data
            $this->keyDataService->write(keyDataIdentifier: $this->keyDataIdentifier,
                cachingTimeInSeconds: $this->cachingTimeInSeconds,
                data: $renderedCode);
        }
        return $renderedCode;
    }

    protected function retrieveDbData(): void
    {
        $newsTb = (new News)->getTable();
        $reactionTb = (new Reaction)->getTable();

        // Get more news reactions count grouped by news
        $listingLimit = ConfigValueEnum::get(ConfigValueEnum::HOT_NEWS_LISTING_LIMIT);
        $this->reactions = Reaction
            ::getByModelType(MODEL_TYPE_NEWS)
            ->leftJoin($newsTb, $newsTb . '.id', '=', $reactionTb . '.model_id')
            ->whereHas('model', function ($query) use ($newsTb) {
                $query->where($newsTb . '.company_id', $this->companyId);
                $query->where($newsTb . '.published', NewsPublishedEnum::PUBLISHED);
            })
            ->groupBy('model_id')
            ->orderBy('reaction_count', 'desc')
            ->limit($listingLimit)
            ->select(
                $reactionTb . '.model_id',
                DB::raw('count(' . $reactionTb . '.id) as reaction_count'))
            ->get()
            ->reject(function (Reaction $reaction) {
                $news = News::find($reaction->model_id);
                return empty($news);
            })
            ->map(function (Reaction $reaction) {
                $news = News::find($reaction->model_id);
                if ( ! empty($news)) {
                    $reaction->news_id = $news->id;
                    $reaction->news_slug = $news->slug;
                    $reaction->news_title = $news->title;
                    $reaction->published_at = $news->created_at;
                }

                return $reaction;
            });
    }
}

It works ok with refresh period 10 minutes and I call it in blade file as :
<livewire:Cacheable.hot-news :companyId="$selectedCompany->id" lazy />

also this component is used inside of other news page component, which has refresh period  in 30 days.
This news page component has code with calling of HotNews component
<!-- CACHEABLE_HOT_NEWS_BLOCK_START -->
<div class="frontend_subtitle d1">
    <livewire:Cacheable.hot-news :companyId="$newsItem->company_id" lazy />
</div>
<!-- CACHEABLE_HOT_NEWS_BLOCK_END -->

The calling of HotNews is wrapped with a CHEABLE_HOT_NEWS_BLOCK tags and I want to cut it with fresh data from component HotNews calling?
But for this I need manually in news page component to get string value of Cacheable.hot-news.
In other words how on news page component to get resulting data of other component HotNews calling ?
